# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource work with postman and browser

Tags: cors, postman

i have this issue 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
when i try to make ajax call from local host to remote web service
 [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTexG.jpg)

what i've tried so far:-

1- successful response with postman
[image here here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlQSV.jpg)

2- i can make a successful GET request direct from browser too
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxvHO.jpg)

thanks for your support in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your server side issue, if you use server side for node js, you can use this module

> [Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Amanur,unfortunately it's a remote API and i have no control over it

Comment: Got it, i have configured my code to send and receive requests to the end point API through my server node js and use Cors module and it's working fine now